# "Failed to setup GCP Project" when creating new Dialogflow agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

The title says it all... is there a quota of some sorts? I just deleted one agent and it still throws the error.
I have a total of 6 (now 5) agents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a quota on the number of projects you can get, and 5 sounds about right from memory. They will generally increase it [upon request](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en), but you need to do so through the [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

Additionally, deleting a project won't immediately free up that space. The project will [still count against your quota](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787) for about 30 days, during which it can be restored.

Comment: This link might be useful for future readers that have Free Trial accounts: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for limits augmentation on Google Cloud Console, create another account, or delete a project.

If you try to delete a project, then you must wait for 30 days before the space is freed up. This is because, while deleting it will immediately keep it from appearing in the console, you can still recover it within 1 month of its deletion.